I want to know if it possible to have GetMaterialApp inside UpgradeAlert which is insisde MaterialApp?
I want to know if it possible to have GetMaterialApp inside UpgradeAlert which is insisde MaterialApp ?
MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: UpgradeAlert(
        child: GetMaterialApp(
            defaultGlobalState: true,
            navigatorKey: navigatorKey,
            initialRoute: "/",
            defaultTransition: Transition.cupertino,
              useMaterial3: true,
              inputDecorationTheme: const InputDecorationTheme(filled: true),
            ),
           
      ),
    );```

